# Current saturation

Tags: power-supply, led, saturation

I have bought a bunch of **24v LED** for the garden, during the first months all of them worked fine, but some after they burned out the power supply. The reason is because they were demanding **high currents**. (Maybe because their low quality or the underground wiring)

I know that the cheap solution would be a simple **fuse** but I realized that a current limiter would be more effective. Then I tried using a laboratory regulated PSU with 1A limit current and all the light turn on nicely.

**Then I was wondering which circuit is the most suitable in order to maintain the current below a chosen limit (p.e 1.5 A) without affecting the voltage applied, in other words, saturate the current maintaining a constant voltage.**

Comment: LEDs are supposed to be driven as constant-current devices. If you drive them with a constant voltage, it is no surprise that the current they draw rises with temperature and they burn out. As for the circuit, there are so many questions on this site about LEDs that you should not have to look far with search terms such as "LED driver" or "current source". In fact, many of them are already linked in the right-hand "related" sidebar. In the very simplest case, you could add a series resistor to linearize the I-V characteristic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you might want to read up on circuits to power LEDs, and ways of powering them. With more reading I thing you can find many good options.

one solution is to use this circuit found in the lm317 datasheet [lm317 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) 
this is set up for 1A limiting. Remember to put a heat-sink on the lm317, I don't want to see any IC's get hurt ;)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faX4hl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think this is definitely the solution I was looking for. Thanks.